# Calling Partial View into Bootstrap Modal through jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net-core

I've viewed several of the answers on Stack about this problem; however, none of the results I've found have solved my problem.

**What I'm trying to do**

I need to dynamically populate a Modal's content but the content contains Razor functions (which is the reason I'm not using JS to populate the Modal). I can't have separate modals because the Razor functions will interfere with each other (one will be called while the other will not be) if I include both Modals on the page. The Controller for the Modals is different from the Page Controller (The page is the Index page & I'm using a separate controller to be more modular)

**My attempt**

I am creating the Modal using an HTMLContent call in my cshtml file:

Widgets.cs

```
        public static IHtmlContent ConfigWidgetModal()
    {

        return new HtmlString("<div class='modal fade' id='configure-widget' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myLargeModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>" +
                                    $"<div class='modal-dialog modal-lg' role='document'>"+
                                        $"<div class='modal-content'>" +
                                            $"<div class='modal-header'>" +
                                                $"<h5 class='modal-title'>Select Widget Information</h5>"+
                                                $"<button type = 'button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>"+
                                            $"</div>"+

                                            $"<div class='modal-body' id='ConfigureBody'>" +
                                                //JavaScript will set the Body depending on the widget type being selected
                                            $"</div>" +
                                            $"<div class='modal-footer'>" +

                                            $"</div>" +
                                        $"</div>" +
                                    $"</div>" +
                                $"</div>");
    }
```

It is called here in Index.cshtml

```
<div>... Index body up here </div>

@*Grid for Widgets*@
@Widgets.Dashboard()

@*Edit/Add/Stop Editing Widget Buttons*@
@Widgets.AddEditButtons()

@* Initial Widget Popup *@
@{ string pagetype = "LP"; }
@Widgets.AddWidgetModal(pagetype)

@* Widget Configuration Popup*@
@Widgets.ConfigWidgetModal()
```

Once the page loads, in my Widgets.js file I'm calling this:

```
 $("#addLine").on('click', function () {
    var url = "/Widgets?handler=TrendConfig";
    var addLineConfig = function () {
        var url = "/Widgets?handler=TrendConfig";
        return $.get(url, function (data) {
            $("#ConfigureBody").html(data);
        });
    }
    addLineConfig().done(function () {
        makeLineWidget();
    });
});
```

Which then should be directing here:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TrendConfig(string adid)
    {
        ViewData["adid"] = adid;
        var myViewData = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary(ViewData);
        return new PartialViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "/Partials/Widgets/TrendGraphWidget",
            ViewData = myViewData
        };
    }
```

However, when `addLineConfig()` returns, it is returning the Layout (i.e. the Navbar and the Footer) not the Partial page below.

```
<script>
//Changes plot options for Line Graph dependent on Activity selection
...some script here about the dropdowns...
</script>
<div class="form-row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-md-3">
    @MyGlobalDropdowns.FinCenter()
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    @MyGlobalDropdowns.Client()
</div>
```

I've tried using an `$.ajax({})` call instead of the `$.get()` but with AJAX, the partial page doesn't render (I don't get anything returned).

Comment: Can you call the endpoint directly from a browser or fiddler and see if the results are what you expect?  Is the returned result the view or the layout?

Comment: Is the routing to your partial directory correct?

Comment: Placing `@Html.Partial("Partials/Widgets/TrendGraphWidget", ViewData)` on the html file returns the partial page correctly.

Comment: @JoshuaLeonard Cannot directly call the endpoint but it appears the routing is correct from my above comment. I can call the above without `ViewData` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using $load(), it has worked well for simply placing a partial in a div for me in the past.

here is an example.

```
$("#ConfigureBody").load("/Controller/TrendConfig/?adid=value");
```

Comment: This causes a 404 error for me. The only url that finds the correct Action on the Controller is `url="/Widgets?handler=TrendConfig"`.

Comment: @KyleShake I normally don't use $.GET, but is it possible to specify you dataType, for normal ajax calls you need to say it is html you are returning.
`url = "/Widgets?handler=TrendConfig";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                url: url,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#ConfigureBody").html(data);
                }
            });`

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried this method and it didn't give me the correct result. It only returned the layout of the page, not the partial page itself.

Comment: @KyleShake what controller is your TrendConfig function in?

Comment: It's in a separate Page Model* -Widgets.cshtml.cs - from the Index page model. I just tried placing the TrendConfig function in the Index Model but it's still not returning the partial page; it's returning a copy of Index.cshtml. We are not using standard MVC. We are using Razor Pages with attached Page Models

Comment: @KyleShake, hmm I do not use Page Models. Only thing I can recommend is either change the Partial Name in your controller or change the URL you are calling, good luck.

Comment: Tried your solution again and for whatever reason it worked this time around. I'm going to test it some more but I could have sworn that this didn't work when I tried it before.

Comment: @KyleShake, cool. It may be possible you didn't include the dataType, because by default its going to try to render json, adding HTML allows the partial to render properly.